# SQL Server Remove Nulls from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT agentIds,
CASE WHEN bvagnt LIKE 'A%A' THEN bvname END AS [Level 1],
CASE WHEN bvagnt LIKE 'A%G' THEN bvname END AS [level 2],
CASE WHEN bvagnt LIKE 'A%M' THEN bvname END AS [level 3]
FROM agents
```

This is the result:

```
agentIds    Level 1         level 2                         level 3
A3090A      JASON COLBY     NULL                            NULL
A5097G      NULL            GARITY ASSOCIATES BROKERAGE     NULL
A8505M      NULL            NULL                            NAIM
```

What I want is, to select a top 1 but I do not want any Null, I want the result to be without the agentIds column:

```
Level 1         level 2                         level 3
JASON COLBY     GARITY ASSOCIATES BROKERAGE     NAIM
```

I did where statement and selected each column not NULL but it didn't work and didn't produce the desired result.

What is the best way to solve this problem?
This is a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(agentid varchar(5),
Level1 varchar(50),
Level2 varchar(50),
Level3 varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES ('A123A', 'NULL', 'PartB', 'NULL')
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES ('A123G', 'PartA', 'NULL', 'NULL')
INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES ('A123M', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'PartC')

SELECT * FROM #table1

DROP TABLE #table1
```

Comment: you temp table appears different than your agents table. are you needing to just get the required result from the temp table?

Answer (score 0):

The following query would work if you expect only one result row:

```
SELECT a.bvname as [Level 1], b.bvname as [Level 2], c.bvname as [Level 3]
FROM
(SELECT bvname FROM agents where bvagnt LIKE 'A%A') a,
(SELECT bvname FROM agents where bvagnt LIKE 'A%G') b,
(SELECT bvname FROM agents where bvagnt LIKE 'A%M') c,
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `distinct`, use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN bvagnt LIKE 'A%A' THEN bvname END) AS [Level 1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN bvagnt LIKE 'A%G' THEN bvname END) AS [level 2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN bvagnt LIKE 'A%M' THEN bvname END) AS [level 3]
FROM agents;
```

Comment: Nope, that does not work, I created a temp table, could you please check it in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT MAX(LEVEL1) LEVEL1
, MAX(LEVEL2) LEVEL2
, MAX(LEVEL3) LEVEL3
FROM #table1
```

I am assuming that you have only 1 legit value per column...